# Zend Framework 2 - Writing and setting a good InputFilter

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework

I'm creating a form in a ZF2 site, where i already solved many problems here:
 [Zend Framework 2 - Submitting a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954866/zend-framework-2-submitting-a-form) (see there to find the code as well).
Now i have another problem: in my controller, `form->isValid()` returns true no matter what. My goal is to have a validation through PHP, then tell the user if everything is good or not via Ajax. I suppose something went wrong with my InputFilter or it's not properly attached to my form.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one as well.
Putting all validators in the same class as the form did the job; this was a mix of (poor) official docs and some forum topics here and somewhere else. Form class now looks this way:

```
<?php
namespace Site\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Zend\InputFilter\Input;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Validator;

class ContactForm extends Form {
    public function __construct($name=null, $options=array ()) {
        parent::__construct ($name, $options);

        $this->setAttributes(array(
            "action" => "./",
        ));


        $nameInput = new Element\Text("nome");
        $nameInput->setAttributes(array(
            "placeholder" => "Nome e cognome",
            "tabindex" => "1"
        ));

        $this->add($nameInput);

        $emailInput = new Element\Text("email");
        $emailInput->setAttributes(array(
            "placeholder" => "Indirizzo e-mail",
            "tabindex" => "2"
        ));

        $this->add($emailInput);

        $phoneInput = new Element\Text("phone");
        $phoneInput->setAttributes(array(
            "placeholder" => "Numero di telefono",
            "tabindex" => "3",
        ));

        $this->add($phoneInput);

        $messageArea = new Element\Textarea("messaggio");
        $messageArea->setAttributes(array(
            "placeholder" => "Scrivi il tuo messaggio",
            "tabindex" => "4"
        ));

        $this->add($messageArea);

        $submitButton = new Element\Button("submit");
        $submitButton
            ->setLabel("Invia messaggio")
            ->setAttributes(array(
                "type" => "submit"
            ));

        $this->add($submitButton);

        $resetButton = new Element\Button("reset");
        $resetButton
        ->setLabel("Cancella")
        ->setAttributes(array(
                "type" => "reset"
        ));

        $this->add($resetButton);

        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

        $nome = new Input("nome");
        $nome->getValidatorChain()
        ->attach(new Validator\StringLength(3));

        $email = new Input("email");
        $email->getValidatorChain()
        ->attach(new Validator\EmailAddress());

        $phone = new Input("phone");
        $phone->getValidatorChain()
        ->attach(new Validator\Digits());

        $message = new Input("messaggio");
        $message->getValidatorChain()
        ->attach(new Validator\StringLength(10));

        $inputFilter->add($nome)
                    ->add($email)
                    ->add($phone)
                    ->add($message);

        $this->setInputFilter($inputFilter);
    }
}
?>
```

I'll try factories later, but for now, this works.